# Difference between making my own database class and using a DBMS

Tags: java, database

Sorry if my question sounds naive, I'm new to programming.

I made a class using `Java` which looks something like this:

```
class Movies {
    private static HashMap<String, Movie> myMovies;
}
```

Key for this hashmap is the unique id assigned to a movie.
The attributes of Movie objects have been read from a csv file.
This class has various methods needed to query and find out information about movies like `getMovieName()`, `getDirectors()`. How different is this approach from using a DBMS like `MongoDB`?

Edit: removed the question - Is this approach inefficient and naive?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does your approach satisfy your needs? If so, it is neither inefficient nor naive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not inefficient. But for such cases instead of making static variable for map you should make Movies a singleton class. In that way all the query methods e.g: getDirectors etc would be public methods of that class and would be called on one instance.

It is recommended to use dbms if :

1. You don't want the map data to be lost when your program ends and you want the data to be persistent.
2. There are many changes in movie data specially from many sources or threads.
3. There are large number of movie data records. DBMS takes care of optimizing different types of queries and it also provides powerful SQL to have many filter options. eg: find movies where actor is Mr X etc.